# Ember handlebars template access deep object property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my Ember app, I have the following code

Component JS

```
row = {};
Ember.set(row[my.constants.fieldKey], "cssType", 'leftPadding')
```

Component HBS

```
{{my-field cssType=(get row (my-field-key 'SECTION_ID' 'FIELD_ID') cssType)}}
```

So I want to pass 'cssType' property of my-field as 'leftPadding' in my component.

The hbs code above does not work.

Essentially I am trying to access a deep/nested object property in my hbs template. I even tried with lookup, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`get` helper accepts object as first argument and path (dot-separated string, like 'level1.level2') as second argument.

If `row` is an array (and `my.constants.fieldKey` is an integer index), you need another helper, which returns object from array by index. For example, ember-composable-helpers addon provide [`object-at`](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#object-at) helper, which can be used like this:

```
{{my-field cssType=(get (object-at (my-field-key 'SECTION_ID' 'FIELD_ID') row) 'cssType')}}
```

If row is an object (and `my.constants.fieldKey` is a string), then this should work:

```
{{my-field cssType=(get row (concat (my-field-key 'SECTION_ID' 'FIELD_ID') '.cssType'))}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...You are quite close to what I am looking for...for some reasons, the 2nd option (get row..) is not working...In my case row is an array...But the value I want is accessed in JS as; row['my-field-key'].cssType

Comment: I am wondering what would be the correct approach to get this is hbs

Comment: Correction...In my case, row is kind of an object.